# Why is my listener not returning any data?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to keep everything modular and I stumbled onto a problem. I want to keep all code related to Firebase Realtime Database and Firebase Cloud Storage in my `message_dao` widget, so I have my `receivedChats` widget calling a `message_dao` function that activates the listener. However, it looks like `receivedChats` is receiving an empty list because when I print out the `chats` variable it's empty.

**message_dao**

```
Future<List> activateChatListener() async { 

    var msg;

    _receivedChatsStream = _messagesRef.onValue.listen((event) {

      event.snapshot.children.forEach((snapshot) {
        dataList.add(snapshot.value);

      });

      //...other code that returns a future...

    });

    return dataList;
  }
```

**receivedChats**

```
class _ReceivedChatsState extends State<ReceivedChats> {
  var chats = [];

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadChats();
  }

Future<void> loadChats() async {

    var dataList = await messageDao.activateChatListener();

    setState(() {
      chats = dataList;
    });

    print('chats: ' + chats.toString()) //This shows an empty list

  }

//...other code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the listbefore the api has finished fetching data

Try this instead

```dart
Future<List> activateChatListener() async { 

    var msg;

    _receivedChatsStream = _messagesRef.onValue.listen((event) {

      event.snapshot.children.forEach((snapshot) {
        dataList.add(snapshot.value);

      });

      //Some other code that returns a future
     return dataList;
    });

    
  }
```

Comment: This gives an error pointing to the `return` statement: `The return type 'List<dynamic>' isn't a 'void', as required by the closure's context.`

Answer (score 0):

Because your `loadChats` will be called once. Instead of storing your data into `dataList` array, you can directly use that snapshot through `StreamBuilder`

Example:

```
class NoteList extends StatelessWidget {
  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Notes"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: db.collection('notes').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else
            return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data.docs.map((doc) {
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(doc.data()['title']),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the [full example](https://mukhtharcm.com/listview-from-firestore/) that you can refer and you can solve your problem.

Comment: But how do I do this and still keep everything modular? How do I keep the code that queries Firebase Realtime Database in my `message_dao` widget and use those results in my `receivedChats` widget?